# android make String in textview recovered via socket

Tags: android, socket.io

I want to make a String in a textView after receiving from server via socket, I try this but it still not working.

```
socket.on("message", new Emitter.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            String data = (String) args[0];
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText(data);
        }
```

PS: I can display the string into log console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the assumption your code is being run from inside an `Activity`, try changing `call` to look like this:

```
@Override
public void call(Object... args) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String data = (String) args[0];
                TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setText(data);
           }
        });
}
```

[Here](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-non-ui-to-ui-thread-communications-part-1-of-5/) is some more reading about `runOnUiThread`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
text.post(new Runnable() {
   text.setText(data);
});
```